# Reshape a variable numpy array

Tags: numpy, reshape

Suppose i have a numpy array `u` with a given shape, a a divisor `d` of the total number of entries in `u`. How can i fastly reshape `u` to be shaped `(something,d)` ?

The case where `u` is just a double should be included as well -> `(1,1)`

The case where `u` is empty should become a `(0,d)` shaped array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `reshape`

```
u.reshape(-1, d)
```

There is no `double` in Python you do you mean `float` ?

In short :

```
import numpy as np

def div_reshape(arr, div):
    if arr.size == 0:
        return np.empty(shape=(0, div))
    elif arr.size == 1:
        return arr.reshape(1, 1)
    else:
        return arr.reshape(-1, d)
```